# How can I call data (Json which is changed by json_encode) in other page.php to show in the other page.php

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, json

First I have to tell you about my requirement. I want to call JSON from in other page (.php) to show in the other page (.php)

How can I do that?

This is my JSON code (this is what I want to call)

```
<?php
 include("Connect.php");
 $Db = mysql_select_db("Examination") or die (" Can't connect the database ");
 $SqlQ = "Select * from engineerin`enter code here`geconomy where Lesson=1 order by rand() limit 0,5";
 $SqlW = "Select * from engineeringeconomy where Lesson=3 order by rand() limit 0,3";
 $SqlA = "Select * from engineeringeconomy where Lessenter code hereon=2 order by rand() limit 0,3";
 $QueryQ = mysql_query($SqlQ) or die (" Can't connect the table ");
 $QueryW = mysql_query($SqlW) or die (" Can't connect the table ");
  $QueryA = mysql_query($SqlA) or die (" Can't connect the table ");
  $Var = array();
  $Var1 = array();
  $Var2 = array();

  print "<table>";
  print "<tr bgcolor=0066FF>";
  print "<td align = center> Lesson </td>";
  print "<td align = center> Question </td>";
  print "<td align = center> Choice1 </td>";
  print "<td align = center> Choice2 </td>";
  print "<td align = center> Choice3 </td>";
  print "<td align = center> Choice4 </td>";
  print "<td align = center> Answer </td>";
  print "</tr>";

 while($ArrayQ = mysql_fetch_array($QueryQ))
 {
     $Var[] = $ArrayQ;
     print "<tr bgclolor=00CCFF>";
     echo "<td>".$ArrayQ['Lesson']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$ArrayQ['Question']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$ArrayQ['Choice1']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$ArrayQ['Choice2']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$ArrayQ['Choice3']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$ArrayQ['Choice4']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$ArrayQ['Answer']."</td>";
     print "</tr>";
 }
 while($ArrayW = mysql_fetch_array($QueryW))
 {
     $Var1[] = $ArrayW;
     print "<tr bgclolor=00CCFF>";
     echo "<td>".$ArrayW['Lesson']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$ArrayW['Question']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$ArrayW['Choice1']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$ArrayW['Choice2']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$ArrayW['Choice3']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$ArrayW['Choice4']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$ArrayW['Answer']."</td>";
     print "</tr>";
 }
 while( $ArrayA = mysql_fetch_array($QueryA))
{
    $Var2[] = $ArrayA;
    print "<tr bgclolor=00CCFF>";
    echo "<td>".$ArrayA['Lesson']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$ArrayA['Question']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$ArrayA['Choice1']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$ArrayA['Choice2']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$ArrayA['Choice3']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$ArrayA['Choice4']."</td>";
     echo "<td>".$ArrayA['Answer']."</td>";
     print "</tr>";
}
 $Json1 = json_encode($Var);
echo $Json1;
?>
```

and this is the other page that i wanna show my data which is called

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
body,td,th {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #000;
    text-align: left;
}
body {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
.white {
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: right;
}
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
.right {
    text-align: right;
}
.right {
    text-align: right;
}
.right {
    text-align: right;
}
.center tr td {
    text-align: center;
}
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
#form5 {
    text-align: left;
}
#center {
    text-align: center;
}
.right {
    text-align: right;
}
</style>
</head>





<body>

<table width="1209" height="711" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="10">
  <tr>
    <td width="1189" height="161" valign="top" bgcolor="#2A3F55"><table width="1200" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="1165" height="163"><img src="../design/banner/bn001.jpg" width="1054" height="163" /></td>
        <td width="35" align="right" valign="bottom"><a href="../../../Downloads/12.php" target="_top">\</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="520"><table width="1200" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0">
      <tr id="center">
        <td width="700" height="500" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#96B0CB"><table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
              <td>
 <body onLoad="begintimer()">
<script language="">
var limit="45:00"
if (document.images){
var parselimit=limit.split(":")
parselimit=parselimit[0]*60+parselimit[1]*1
}
function begintimer(){
if (!document.images)
return
if (parselimit==1)
// เหตุการณ์ที่ต้องการให้เกิดขึ้น
//window.location='p06.php'; ถ้าต้องการให้กระโดดไปยัง Page อื่น
frmTest.submit();
else{
parselimit-=1
curmin=Math.floor(parselimit/60)
cursec=parselimit%60
if (curmin!=10)
curtime="เวลาที่เหลือ <font color=red> "+curmin+" </font>นาที กับ <font color=red>"+cursec+" </font>วินาที "
else
if(cursec==00)
{
alert('ใกล้จะหมดเวลาแล้วนะ');
}
else
{
curtime="เวลาที่เหลือ <font color=red> "+curmin+" </font>นาที กับ <font color=red>"+cursec+" </font>วินาที "
}
document.getElementById('dplay').innerHTML = curtime;
setTimeout("begintimer()",1000)
}
}
//-->
</script>
<div id=dplay ></div>
<form name="frmTest" action="../../../Downloads/15.php">

</form>

&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <table width="978" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="center">
            <tr class="center">
              <th width="47" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="center" scope="col">ข้อ</th>
              <th width="35" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="center" scope="col"><a href="p031.php">1</a></th>
              <th width="35" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="center" scope="col"><a href="p032.php">2</a></th>
              <th width="35" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="center" scope="col"><a href="p033.php">3</a></th>
              <th width="35" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="center" scope="col"><a href="p034.php">4</a></th>
              <th width="35" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="center" scope="col"><a href="p035.php">5</a></th>
              <th width="35" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="center" scope="col"><a href="p036.php">6</a></th>
              <th width="35" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="center" scope="col"><a href="p037.php">7</a></th>
              <th width="35" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="center" scope="col"><a href="p038.php">8</a></th>
              <th width="35" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="center" scope="col"><a href="p039.php">9</a></th>
              <th width="35" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="center" scope="col"><a href="p0310.php">10</a></th>
              <th width="35" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="center" scope="col"><a href="p0311.php">11</a></th>
              <th width="35" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="center" scope="col"><a href="p0312.php">12</a></th>
              <th width="35" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="center" scope="col"><a href="p0313.php">13</a></th>
              <th width="35" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="center" scope="col"><a href="p0314.php">14</a></th>
              <th width="35" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="center" scope="col"><a href="p0315.php">15</a></th>
              <th width="35" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="center" scope="col"><a href="p0316.php">16</a></th>
              <th width="35" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="center" scope="col"><a href="p0317.php">17</a></th>
              <th width="35" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="center" scope="col"><a href="p0318.php">18</a></th>
              <th width="35" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="center" scope="col"><a href="p0319.php">19</a></th>
              <th width="35" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="center" scope="col"><a href="p0320.php">20</a></th>
              <th width="35" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="center" scope="col"><a href="p0321.php">21</a></th>
              <th width="35" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="center" scope="col"><a href="p0322.php">22</a></th>
              <th width="35" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="center" scope="col"><a href="p0323.php">23</a></th>
              <th width="35" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="center" scope="col"><a href="p0324.php">24</a></th>
              <th width="35" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" class="center" scope="col"><a href="p0325.php">25</a></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">ตอบ</td>
              <td width="35" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="35" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="35" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
  </table>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
          <table width="800" border="0" align="center" dir="ltr">
            <tr>
              <td align="center" valign="middle"><p id="Question`">ข้อที่ 1:`
              </p></td>
            </tr>
        </table> 
         <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
            <span class="center">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio" value="radio" />
              ก ...</label>
              </span>
        </form>
          <form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="">
            <span class="center">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio2" id="radio2" value="radio2" />
                ข ...</label>
              </span>
          </form>
          <form id="form3" name="form3" method="post" action="">
            <span class="center">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio3" id="radio3" value="radio3" />
                ค ...</label>
              </span>
          </form>
          <form id="form4" name="form4" method="post" action="">
            <span class="center">
              <label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio4" id="radio4" value="radio4" />
                ง ...</label>
              </span>
          </form>
          <blockquote>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <table width="1082" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <tr>
                <td width="570"><form id="form5" name="form5" method="post" action="">
                  <label for="ส่"></label>
                  <img src="../design/icon/icon011.jpg" width="146" height="57" alt="sent" />
                  </form></td>
                <td width="512" class="right"><img src="../design/icon/icon020.jpg" width="60" height="60" alt="next" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
</blockquote>
          <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
        </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="Question"> </div> // this place what i want to show the data which i called//


</body>
</html>
```

how can i do it tell me plz??   thank you so much ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pull that json data into the view dynamically, use an ajax request http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Example:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', // or GET
        url: '/to/your/data',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        statusCode: {
            200: function(data) {

                // Your returned json available here
                // Access with data var or whatever you set above

            },
            500: function() {

                // Error

            }

        }

    });
```